# Отладка кода Веб-Сервиса (Xdebug, NetBeans)

Tags: php, отладка, netbeans, soap, xdebug

Добрый день,

при разработке Веб-сервиса столкнулся со следующей проблемой: не могу запустить отладчик, если запуск скрипта происходит не из NetBeans, а посредством запроса на SOAP-Сервер этого скрипта от программы - клиента. Разрабатываемый скрипт крутится на локальном апаче на винде (XAMPP), на этой же машине запускается и программа-клиент. Всё локально.

Как мне зацепиться отладчиком к процессу, созданному программой-клиентом? Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, как это решается.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Только если вы запускаете SoapServer из IDE тогда можно будет перехватить и отладить. Иначе придётся подключаться когда он уже заработал удаленно через remote_debug

Answer (score 1):

Решил. В моём случае я добавил к URL SOAP-Сервиса, вызываемого программой-клиентом, GET-параметр "XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug". Запускаю отладчик NetBeans, посылаю запрос - работает.